# product of spaces is a manifold. Are the spaces?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and that $X\times Y$ is a topological manifold. It seems that we can't conclude that $X$ or $Y$ are manifolds themselves ([this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32527/product-of-spaces-is-a-manifold-with-boundary-what-can-be-said-about-the-spaces)).

**EDIT** :Are there situations where we can say that $Y$ is a manifold given some $X$. For example, maybe if $X = (0,1)$, $(0,1)^{d}$, or $S^{1}$?

If so, any idea how one might prove these.

Thank you.

Comment: The question you linked to contains an exa,ple where $X = \Bbb R$, $X \times Y \cong \Bbb R^4$, yet $Y$ is not a manifold.

Comment: I see. Are there any examples where this occurs in lower dimension?

Comment: Related: [Simpler version of dogbone space construction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405312/simpler-version-of-dogbone-space-construction)

Comment: @Joseph123: There are no lower dimensional examples. The basic reason is that if $X\times Y$ is a manifold then $X$ and $Y$ are homology manifolds and each homology manifold of dimension $\le 2$ is a manifold.